# phantomjs - setting breakpoints on the client code

Tags: javascript, debugging, phantomjs

I found [this troubleshooting page](http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting.html) which mentions a way to run a debugger but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried to get the most basic example to work and failed miserably. Namely

*runner.js* (example from the [quickstart](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html) tutorial)

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
  system = require('system'),
  t, address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
  phantom.exit();
}

t = Date.now();
address = system.args[1];
page.open(address, function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('FAIL to load the address');
  } else {
    t = Date.now() - t;
    console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

*test.html*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Script</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Script</h1>
  </body>
  <script>
    debugger;
    console.log("hello world;")
  </script>
</html>
```

And then I run

```
$ phantomjs --remote-debugger-autorun=yes --remote-debugger-port=9000 /tmp/runner.js /tmp/test.html
Loading time 6 msec
Phantom::exit() called but not quitting in debug mode.
^C%                                                                                                                                                                    
$ phantomjs --remote-debugger-autorun=yes /tmp/runner.js /tmp/test.html         
Loading time 6 msec
$ phantomjs /tmp/runner.js /tmp/test.html         
Loading time 6 msec
```

What did I get wrong? I was expecting a repl or a debug interface or something, did I misunderstand the documentation?

EDIT: Just to clarify `localhost:9000` and the `debugger;` statement was indeed ignored - ie. there was 'hello world;' in the console